# how to add items to the spinner dynamically in android?

Tags: android

how to add items to the spinner  dynamically in android?

Answer (score 34):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
spinnerAdapter.add("value");
spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

the above is in case of the array adapter, I believe you know how to populate values with ArrayAdapter .

How can we do this in case of the  SimpleCursorAdapter, i.e if we have 2 spinners and if we select the values of one spinner (that is getting the value from SimpleCursorAdapter) depending on some criteria the other spinner should be filled with values. how can we achieve that?

Comment: i had the same question, i followed your answer, it works, but text is white at the spinner initial value. Any hints?

Comment: I used the example at this post and it worked: https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-spinner-add-item-dynamically.html

Answer (score 8):

By calling [`ArrayAdapter.add`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)) to the Spinner's ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow this way**

```
public static void selectSpinnerItemByValue(Spinner spnr, long value){
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) spnr.getAdapter();
for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getCount(); position++)
{
    if(adapter.getItemId(position) == value)
    {
        spnr.setSelection(position);
        return;
    }
} }
```

**You can use the above like:**

```
selectSpinnerItemByValue(spinnerObject, desiredValue);
```

you can also select by index directly like

```
spinnerObject.setSelection(index);
```