# Populate android spinner dynamically

Tags: android

I have created a `TextView` in android like the code below:

```
txtv = new TextView(this);
txtv.setText("text");
ll.addView(txtv);
```

Same way I have created a `spinner`:

```
spinner = new Spinner(this);
ll.addView(spinner);
```

But I am unable to populate value on the `spinner`. Most tutorials giving populating `spinner` with `ArrayAdapter` but it is taking `id` of `xml`, like `R.id....`. Since I am creating dynamic, I can't do like that way. How can I populate `spinner` dynamically?

Comment: duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479667/populate-android-spinner-dynamically)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2160518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get layout

```
View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.layoutID);
Cerate spinner

   Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
//Make sure you have valid layout parameters.
spinner .setLayoutParams(new     LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerList);
                spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
Then add spinner to view

((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(spinner );
```

Answer (score 2):

Add in bellow way

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayListString();
 list.add("First");
 list.add("Second");
 ArrayAdapter adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list); 
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It worked for me, the answer marked as good has some undeclared variables and make it harder to understand

Comment: `new ArrayListString()` - missing some angle brackets there?

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a textview in a spinner. Spinner already has a CheckedTextView inside the rows. Here's an example you can use.

```
yourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item){
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
CheckedTextView view = (CheckedTextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                return view;
            }
        };

yourSpinner.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

You simply add a String to your adapter by using

```
yourAdapter.add("firstRow");
```

You don't actually need the getDropDownView, it just helps you if need to customise a little.

Comment: I don't have android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item . Because it is dynamic layout. I have LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);

Comment: Well then you have to create a custom adapter, you don't need to write android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item as your layout, you can create a row layout and set it, then you can set the contents in getView().

Comment: You can skip that parameter, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item is the visual look of the control, if you skip it the control will look like your current style