# Populate android spinner dynamically

Tags: android

I have created a Text View in android like the code below:

```
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);

txtv = new TextView(this);
txtv.setText("text");
ll.addView(txtv);
```

Same way I have created a spinner:

```
spinner = new Spinner(this);
ll.addView(spinner);
```

But I am unable to populate value on the spinner. Most tutorials giving populating spinner with array adapter but it is taking id of xml, like R.id. .... Since I am creating dynamic I cant do like that way. How can I populate spinner dynamically?

Comment: You can create one instance of `ArrayAdapter` add the text you enter in `TextView` into instance of `ArrayAdapter` and set that instance to spinner. You can make it on just one button click

Comment: duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479597/populate-android-spinner-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a String array then use that array to populate your spinner.

Like this    `String[] value = new String[]{ "one","two","three".....};`

Try this too `ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();`

```
list.add(your_value);
```

then `String[] value=list.toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an impementation of SpinnerAdapter or BaseAdapter and set it as the adapter of the Spinner.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html

You return the views through the adapter from the array.

Also please consider renaming your variables. They aren't very descriptive and naming a variable 11 is poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("token", prefrences.getUserData().getToken());
map.put("u_id", prefrences.getUserData().getId());

CaregoryID.add("0");
Category.add("Select Category");

appDialogs.showProgressDialog();

callAPiActivity.doPost((Activity) mContext, map, "URL NAME", new GetApiResult() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccesResult(JSONObject result) throws JSONException {
        appDialogs.hideProgressDialog();
        JSONArray countryArray = result.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < countryArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject countryObj = countryArray.getJSONObject(i);
            CaregoryID.add(countryObj.getString("c_id"));
            Category.add(countryObj.getString("c_title_price"));
        }

        categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Category);

        categoryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        spinnerCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

    }
}
```