# How to add data in two spinners dynamically from string.xml in android?

Tags: android, string, dynamic, spinner

I want to add data in spinner dynamically. 
Like I have 3 spinners. Data of first spinner is fixed.
Depending on data selection from spinner 1 the data of second spinner will be fixed. And depending on selected data from spinner 2, the data of 3rd spinner will be fixed. 
And I want to get data from string-array. How to add this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add items to the spinner dynamically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160518/how-to-add-items-to-the-spinner-dynamically-in-android)

Comment: But I want to add data from string in second and third spinner.