# Is there a way to get the item position on Spinner Object by only focusing and not by OnItemSelected in Android?

Tags: android, position, spinner

Is there a way to get the item position on Spinner Object by only focusing and not by OnItemSelected in Android?

Cause i need to add/increment an item when everytime the last item of spinner is focus..

Answer (score 2):

Try this.It is working fine.

```
@Override
 public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        final int position, long id) {

    parent.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            spinner.requestFocusFromTouch();
            long pos = spinner.getItemIdAtPosition(position+1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position : " +pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks naveen, but what do you mean by sp2? i got an error.

Comment: sp2 means Spinner.I edited the code now.Please check it once.Can you voteup my answer ? @Jun M.

Comment: @JunM.  I was looking for such question. How you add/increment an item when everytime the last item of spinner is focus ?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160518/how-to-add-items-to-the-spinner-dynamically-in-android @JaiminModi

Comment: @Naveen my question is how to find the item position by focusing? not by onItemSelected.. btw Thanks

Comment: @JaiminModi im stil stock with this, let me know if you already solve this.